# Error not found: git when install npm package on windows

Tags: git, npm, window

I'm trying to install this package through npm `npm install bigwheel` on windows using webstorm IDE.

I'm getting

> "Error: not found: git" "This is most likely not a problme with npm itself. Please check if you have git installed and in yout Path"

I have https://git-for-windows.github.io/ installed, how do i check the path and fix this error?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please find at which location on your machine git is installed. e.g. `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` and append this to your `PATH` variable in environment variables.

To append to path please follow below steps:

1. Right click on **This PC** or **My Computer** & select **Properties**
2. Select **Advanced System Settings**
3. Select **Environment Variables**
4. In **System Variables** locate **PATH** variable
5. Select **Edit** and append this **path**
6. Click **OK** & restart command prompt

Execute below command from new command prompt after appending this:

```
git --version
```

It should display something like:

```
git version 2.9.0.windows.1
```

After following these steps, try to install npm package and see whether the problem is resolved.

Comment: Where do i append to PATH? do i do that when runnig "npm install bigwheel" can you show me an example. i have my path to git, which is the same as yours C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

Comment: Click **OK** on Environment variables as well.

Comment: Please execute `echo %PATH%` on your command prompt and paste the output here.

Comment: Your instructions were great, just needed to restart my machine after

Comment: I'm glad this helped in solving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, environment...there are 2 issues here:
Installation SourceTree does not mean git.exe is installed, so you need to install latest version first
Then go this url (https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting) and doing an npm reinstall in the directory where I have my project fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try **git cmd**. I try and work it